# Как записать в массив "слова"?

Tags: c

Здравствуйте!)

Как создать (объявить) массив, чтоб его элементы содержали слово (или присвоить)? К примеру, имеется массив a[i], i = 1..n, a[1]="name1", a[2]="name2", .. a[n]="nameN":) Чтоб потом на экране в определенных значениях X,Y их выводить. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Набираем

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *numbers[] = {"0", "1", "2"};

void main(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]); i++) {
        printf("%d == %s\n", i , numbers[i]);
    }
}
```

запускаем

```
$ gcc -std=c99 numbers.c -o numbers && ./numbers
```

и получаем

```
0 == 0
1 == 1
2 == 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял то вы говорите о типе String.
Без этого типа такого можно добиться с помощью массивов, указателей и функции strcpy().

```
int STR_COUNT = 10; //количество слов в массиве
char **strings = new char*[STR_COUNT]; //объявление массива слов

int NUMBER = 3; //выбираем номер элемента массива
strcpy(strings[NUMBER], "слово"); //присваиваем значение элементу
```

Примерно так. Более подробно можете почитать в этой [теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2042/%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D1%81).

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то так

Динамически:

```
int n; // число строк
int m; // длина каждой строки
int i;
char ** ptr = alloc(n);
for (i = 0; i<n; ++i)
    ptr[i] = alloc(m);
```

Статически

```
char ** ptr = { "строка1", "строка2", "строка3" };
```

Comment: А что такое alloc? И что значит alloc(n) - выделение n байт для n указателей?