# Определение массива строк в С

Tags: c

Я пробую определить массив строк двумя способами.

Первый вариант:

```
char *numbers[] = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4" };
```

Второй вариант:

```
char **numbers = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4" };
```

Оба варианта компилируются, но во втором случае компилятор выдает предупреждения и программа падает после запуска. Что не так во втором случае?

Сам код:

```
char **number = (char **)numbers;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    puts(numbers[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дело в том, что, `char** strings` и `char* strings[2]` - это переменные разных типов. Отсюда и все проблемы.

Можно сделать так:

```
char* strings[]={"111", "222"};
char** pStrings = strings;
```

Для добавления в массив можно попробовать такой код:

```
char **pStrings = 0;  // массив строк (обратите внимание на две звездочки **)
int str_count = 0;    // количество элементов в массиве

void AddString (const char *str)
{
  char **newStrings = new char* [str_count+1];
  memcpy (newStrings, pStrings, sizeof(char*)*str_count);
  delete [] pStrings;
  pStrings = newStrings;
  pStrings[str_count] = new char [strlen (str)+1];
  strcpy (pStrings[str_count], str);
  str_count++;
}
```

Дело в том, что создав указатель, потом нужно выделить место в памяти для переменной. В синтаксисе С это будет выглядеть так:

```
char **newStrings = new char* [str_count+1];
```

То есть как бы создается массив массивов с явным выделением памяти под каждый элемент.
Прошу прощения, если что-то не так, давно не было практики на С, сильно привык к garbage collector'у.

Comment: Если это действительно C, необходимо new/delete заменить на malloc/free. И const убрать из параметра функции, если память не изменяет.

Comment: Уточнение насчёт разных типов: во втором случае мы имеем переменную типа char **, и инициализацию char *[], и компилятор ругается не только на несоответствие типа, но и количества элементов - скаляру присваивается несколько значений.
Если вместо
    char **numbers = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4" };
написать
    char **numbers = (char *[]){ "0", "1", "2", "3", "4" };
то всё нормально. По крайней мере с gcc -std=c99
Разница - лишний указатель **numbers во втором случае, поскольку там создаётся массив указателей, адрес которого и присваивается numbers

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы не сделать массив указателей? И потом на каждый указатель направить строку. Например:

```
int* massiv[];//Массив указателей
massiv = new int[someNumber];//Выделение памяти под массив указателей
for(int i = 0; i < someNumber; i++)
    massiv[i] = new char[stringLen];//Выделение памяти под каждую строку
```

Мог напутать в элементарных вещах, поэтому не ругайте :)